How to get values of the first element of fetch reponse
I try to get values of the first element of my fetch request.
Here you can see my code -> the result of the fetch-request is assigned to "data" variable.
const ListRezept = (props) => {
   const url_id = props.params.id;
   const [data, setData] = useState(null);
   const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
   const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  
   useEffect(() => {
    const abortCont = new AbortController();

    setTimeout(() => {
    fetch('https://abc.4.azurestaticapps.net/data-api/rest/Rezept?$filter=RezeptId eq '+ url_id)
       .then(res => {
          if (!res.ok) { // error coming back from server
            console.log("error");
            throw Error('Could not fetch the data for that resource!');
          } 
          return res.json();
       })
       .then(data => {
        setIsPending(false);
        setData(data.value);
        setError(null);
       })
       .catch(err => {
        if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
          console.log('fetch aborted')
        } else {
          // auto catches network / connection error
          setIsPending(false);
          setError(err.message);
        }
       });
 }, []);

     // abort the fetch
     return () => abortCont.abort();
 }, []) 
 }

The structure of the returned data.value (after json()-Parsing) you can see here structure of parsed data.value
How can I assign the first element of returned "json()" value to an variable?
Later on I want to pass this "data" variable to another page and work with these values in gatsby.
Pseudocode:
// assign first element to a variable
const aenderungsdatum = data[0].aenderungsdatum


Please add information about the structure of the returned JSON.

I added the structure of the json()-parsed data.value object into my initial question ;)

What code produces the data in your screenshot? You don't appear to have any console.log() lines for that so where does it come from? At a guess, I'd say you want setData(data.value.data)

The data in screenshot is produced via console.log(json.value). How du you suppose to have a further "data" at the end?

@user23348508: Where do you have a console.log(json.value) in your code?  Where is there even a variable called json?  The structure shown in the image is an object with a property called data, and that property is an array.  So if this is a representation of whatever json.value is then you could use json.value.data[0] to access the first element of that array.  In your code you have multiple different variables called data.  One data is set to the value of the other data object's value property.  Perhaps you've confused yourself with your variable names?

sorry... The json was coming from the answer of Guido Flohr. The final solution to my original question is: const aenderungsdatum = data.data[0].Aenderungsdatum after setData(data.value);

Your problem is apparently this piece of code:
       .then(data => {
        setIsPending(false);
        setData(data.value);
        setError(null);
       })

The third line has to be setData(data.data.value).  And it will become clearer, if you rename the lambda parameter to something like json:
       .then(json => {
        setIsPending(false);
        setData(json.data.value);
        setError(null);
       })

Additional problem: Your object has no property value according to the screenshot provided.  So the final code should look like this:
       .then(json => {
        setIsPending(false);
        setData(json.data);
        console.log(`last change: ${json.data[0]['Aenderungsdatum']`);
        setError(null);
       })


okay, I understood your thought. But how to get first element of "json" object? Especially  how to get aenderungsdatum of the first element of my object and set it to variable?
